# How to check object in React for null or empty or undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following sequence of code in `React`:

```
{financialPerformance && (
  financialPerformance.isConfirmed ? (
    <L.Text txtGray>Confirmed</L.Text>
  ) : (
    <L.Text txtGray>Not Confirmed</L.Text>
  )
)}
```

I have to check `financialPerformance` itself as well for `null` or empty or `undefined` and display **"Non Confirmed"** message. I mean on first appearance of `financialPerformance` object.

```
{financialPerformance && (
```

How can I do that inside or out of block above?

Comment: Why not just `(financialPerformance && financialPerformance.isConfirmed) ? "confirmed" : "not confirmed"`. Combine the two conditions into one ternary

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Due to `null` and `undefined` will be evaluated to `false` in boolean context - you can just combine your checks at one place:

```
{
  financialPerformance && financialPerformance.isConfirmed ? (
    <L.Text txtGray>Confirmed</L.Text>
  ) : (
    <L.Text txtGray>Not Confirmed</L.Text>
  )
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could be explicit and do the following...

```
// Check specifically for null or undefined
if(financialPerformance === null || financialPerformance === undefined) {
            // Code...
}

// Checking for zero, could be returned ( not sure on your data )
if(financialPerformance === 0 || financialPerformance) {
             // Code...
}
```